# jquery-1.10.2.js:8720 - POST xxx.xxx.....:xxxx/Contacts/NewContact 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-server-2012

I'm having that error when calling to a partial view from an ajax request to my IIS server web application (an action that returns a partial view). What's more, this is exactly the same web app (the same bin, Scripts, Views, etc) that is currently working. Can someone give a solution, please!!!
In addition, when I search the url in my browser it gives me 404 error and I don't know why because the other web is working perfectly just changed the web.config and some urls in it.

Ajax call:

```
function newContact() {
        //debugger;
        $("#divProcces").show();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("NewContact", "Contacts")',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (partialView) {
                //debugger;
                $('#divContactContent').html(partialView);
                $('#modalEditContact').modal("show");
                $("#divProccess").hide();
                return false;
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Please post more error information about 500 and 404. and what changes did you make to web.config and url.

Comment: @samwu Web configs are the same except the database in the connection string and some directories that I use for storage photos and files. Ah! There's google client id and its secret different from the others of course because I use oauth of google

Comment: can you show me your what the ajax function do?

Comment: okay, i'm going to edit the question

Comment: The 404 error is caused by a wrong http method. If you directly input the url in the browser to get the content of a post, it definitely will return a 404 error. Regarding the 500 error, please show me the specific error message.